# How do I subtract n Quarters to each element in a `date` column in a Pandas Dataframe to create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Firm     Date          Quarter
A        2019-06-30    0
A        2019-06-30    1
A        2019-06-30    2
A        2019-06-30    3
B        2017-06-30    0 
B        2017-06-30    1
B        2017-06-30    2 
B        2017-06-30    3
```

I would like to create a new column `QDate` by subtracting the number of quarters in the column `Quarter` (End of Quarter Date) to each of the dates in the column `Date`, so I get the following table:

```
Firm     Date          Quarter  QDate
A        2019-06-30    0        2019-06-30
A        2019-06-30    1        2019-03-31
A        2019-06-30    2        2018-12-31
A        2019-06-30    3        2018-09-30
B        2017-06-30    0        2017-06-30
B        2017-06-30    1        2017-03-31
B        2017-06-30    2        2016-12-31 
B        2017-06-30    3        2016-09-30
```

given that I have a large number of companies and different values in the column `Date`, I would like to know how to create a function I could use to do this automatically, I know that there is the function: `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()`, so essentially, I guess it would be applying the following code to each of the rows of the dataset but with the parameter 'n' based on the column "Quarter":

```
df["QDate"] = df["Date"] - pd.tseries.offsets
.QuarterEnd(n = 0, 1, 2, 3...)
```

Would be very grateful if you could help me with this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the `Date` column to pandas `datetime` series, then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `Quarter` column to [`pd.offsets.QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html) and subtract it from `Date` to get the desired results:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['QDate'] = df['Date'] - df['Quarter'].map(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd)
```

Result:

```
  Firm       Date  Quarter      QDate
0    A 2019-06-30        0 2019-06-30
1    A 2019-06-30        1 2019-03-31
2    A 2019-06-30        2 2018-12-31
3    A 2019-06-30        3 2018-09-30
4    B 2017-06-30        0 2017-06-30
5    B 2017-06-30        1 2017-03-31
6    B 2017-06-30        2 2016-12-31
7    B 2017-06-30        3 2016-09-30
```

Comment: Dear Shubham Sharma, many thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Happy coding :).